# Access WSDL webservice with .svc extension in iphone

Tags: ios

Hiii..
I am creating one application in which i am using web service named "http://192.168.0.51/iPadDataCollection/Service.svc?wsdl" . I have parsed class from this web service and i have written the code to access one method named TestConnection but i am getting error 400 (Bad Request). 
Can anyone help me to solve this issue??
Thanx in advance.

```
BasicHttpBinding_IServiceBinding *binding=[[Service  BasicHttpBinding_IServiceBinding]initWithAddress:@"http://192.168.0.51/iPadDataCollection/Service.svc?wsdl"];
binding.logXMLInOut = YES;

Service_TestConnection *request = [[Service_TestConnection alloc] init];
request.Unique_Id =txtID.text;

[binding TestConnectionAsyncUsingParameters:request delegate:self];

[spinner startAnimating];
[request release];
```

Comment: I got the solution from this link http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.in/2010/06/calling-wcf-service-from-iphone.html